# Join calendar table to count query with Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join a calendar table to my count query per day, in order to show all dates for a given range, not just the ones where there is a count.

At the moment my query for a count for the last 7 days from today:

```
ctn    followupdate
2      2019-07-20
1      2019-07-19
```

where I am trying to get all 7 days shown, as below:

```
ctn    followupdate
0      2019-07-21
2      2019-07-20
1      2019-07-19
0      2019-07-18
0      2019-07-17
0      2019-07-16
0      2018-07-15
```

My original query is:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt, date(followed_up_on) AS followupdate 
FROM wt_follow_up 
WHERE followed_up_on > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY followupdate
```

I have set up a calendar_table with all dates to 2040.

```
dt
2010-01-01
...
2040-01-01
```

How do I join this table to get the desired result? I have tried:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt, date(followed_up_on) AS followupdate
FROM wt_follow_up 
WHERE followed_up_on > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
JOIN calendar_table c ON c.dt BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY c.dt
```

but this gives an unspecified syntax error on the JOIN line

EDIT:
wt_follow_up table structure:

```
wt_followup_id int(11)
wt_id (int11)
followed_up_on (timestamp)
```

example data

```
wt_followup_up      wt_id    followed_up_on
1                    30      2019-07-20 07:34:56
2                    32      2019-07-20 07:34:56
```

calendar_table:

```
dt
2010-01-01
...
2040-01-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `where` clause should be after join and to avoid `date()` function used `c.dt` in `select`

```
SELECT count(f.wt_followup_up) as cnt, c.dt AS followupdate
FROM calendar_table c 
LEFT JOIN wt_follow_up f ON c.dt=date(f.followed_up_on)
WHERE c.dt between (curdate()- interval 7 day) and curdate()
GROUP BY c.dt
```

Comment: this still only gives the days where there is a count, not all 7 days.

Comment: @warrenfitzhenry Added Left  join so the records from master table will be fetched. If no match then it returns 0

Comment: still the same. note that `f.followed_up_on` is a datetime (`2019-07-20 12:00:00`), hence the `date` in the first line. I tried adding this in the join: `LEFT JOIN wt_follow_up f ON date(f.followed_up_on)=c.dt`. If I don't o this, the results is empty...

Comment: can you add table structure and sample insert records, so that can check locally.

Comment: getting there! this returns `cnt: 1,  followupdate: NULL` for all 6 dates there wasn't a count, and `ctn:2, followupdate: 2019-07-20` for the one date there was a count.

Comment: @warrenfitzhenry updated answer. Took `wt_followup_up` as primary key

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be implemented as below-

```
SELECT dt,COUNT(*)
FROM calendar_table 
LEFT JOIN your_table
ON calendar_table.dt= your_table.followupdate 
WHERE dt BETWEEN 'Date1' AND 'Date2'
-- Filter dates you wants data for, 
-- Give value to Date1 and Date2 as per your requirement
GROUP BY dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query. The dt table should be on LEFT.

```
SELECT c.dt, count(*) AS count FROM `calendar_table` AS C LEFT JOIN `wt_follow_up` AS f ON c.dt = date(f.followed_up_on) where c.dt between '2019-07-15' and '2019-07-21' GROUP BY c.dt
```

Comment: thanks. why does the count return 1 for days when there should be none?

Comment: It should not. Could you please set up a fiddle with a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You should drive from your calendar table and left join to the follow up table. There should be no need to hard code dates on your where clause and it's important that you remove the time element from your data and now(). so given

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int,    followupdate timestamp);
insert into t values
(2  ,    '2019-07-20 01:00:01'),(3  ,    '2019-07-20 02:00:00'),
(1  ,    '2019-07-19 05:00:01');

and dates

+---------------------+------------+
| now()               | dte        |
+---------------------+------------+
| 2019-07-21 09:24:31 | 2019-07-14 |
| 2019-07-21 09:24:31 | 2019-07-15 |
| 2019-07-21 09:24:31 | 2019-07-16 |
| 2019-07-21 09:24:31 | 2019-07-17 |
| 2019-07-21 09:24:31 | 2019-07-18 |
| 2019-07-21 09:24:31 | 2019-07-19 |
| 2019-07-21 09:24:31 | 2019-07-20 |
+---------------------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

select d.dte,count(t.id) cnt
from   dates d
left   join   t on d.dte = date(t.followupdate)
where  d.dte >= date_sub(date(now()),interval  7 day) and
         d.dte <= date(now())
group  by d.dte
order  by d.dte desc

 +------------+-----+
| dte        | cnt |
+------------+-----+
| 2019-07-21 |   0 |
| 2019-07-20 |   2 |
| 2019-07-19 |   1 |
| 2019-07-18 |   0 |
| 2019-07-17 |   0 |
| 2019-07-16 |   0 |
| 2019-07-15 |   0 |
| 2019-07-14 |   0 |
+------------+-----+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t place the filters after the join but on the table before it, Otherwise you are placing an inner instead a left one.

```
    SELECT count(f.wt_followup_up) as cnt, c.dt AS followupdate FROM calendar_table c 
    LEFT JOIN 
    wt_follow_up f ON ( c.dt=date(f.followed_up_on) and c.dt between (curdate()- interval 7 day) 
   and curdate() )
    GROUP BY c.dt
```